# Spring MVC and Bootstrap - css, img working .js not working

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I'm using STS Eclipse with Spring Template MVC project.
I want to use Bootstrap and I created under webapp/resources the css, js and img directory and I placed all the needed files under those folders.
I have no problem with the .css files while I cannot locate the .js files. The application correctly works with external .js references.

Here's the Dispatcher servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.dani.bootstrap" />



</beans:beans>
```

Here's the jsp part for the js scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="resources/js/bootstrap.js"/>"> </script>
<!-- <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"/>"> </script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" />"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.min.js" />"></script>
```

I need to know what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for more visibility, you should separate your url variable and your script. You should include in your URL the complete path by adding "/". Try this:

```
<mvc:resources location="resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" var="jqueryUrl"/>
<script src="${jqueryUrl}" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
```

Comment: I actually just refactored to avoid this ... each to their own I guess

Comment: you're still missing in your c:url the '/' : `<c:url value="/resources/js/...`

Comment: @Rigg802 <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> is actually doing what it's supposed to do.
What solved my problem was those two lines:
<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" var="jqueryUrl"/>
<script src="${jqueryUrl}" type="text/javascript">.

Thank you